# How to calculate Geometric distribution expected value by Law of total expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, geometric-distribution

Could anyone help me with this problem, please? I have to calculate the expected value of the geometric distribution using the law of total expectation:

$$E(X) = E[E(X | Y )]$$

I think I have to consider $X$ being a random variable with geometric distribution and I know how to operate with this law, but the problem doesn't specify what I should consider $Y$ to be.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes in grammar, English is not my first language.

Edit: This problem comes from a lecture of my university in Probability II. My professor proposed this exercise saying that we should discover $Y$ by ourselves and then do the math to reach $1/p$ (the expected value of geometric distribution). Unfortunately, he didn't provide anymore context or tips :(

Edit2: What I did so far:

$ E[X/Y] =\\ \sum_{y=0}^1 \sum_{x=1}^\infty \ x\
P[X=x/Y=y]\ P[Y=y] = \\ \sum_{x=2}^\infty \ x\ P[X=x]\ +\ P[X=1] $

Comment: It's funny how the majority of people who apologise for their English speak it very well indeed. Maybe *we* should apologise for forcing this to be an English-only site

Comment: Thank you for the compliment :)

Comment: I can't think of an appropriate $Y$ either. Is this problem from a book or lecture? Maybe you could quote it in full and it'll become clearer to someone. A classical example of using the LTE is to compute mean of randoms sums $X=\sum_{i=1}^Y A_i$ where $A_i$ IID with mean $\mu$, and $Y$ is geometrically distributed, independent of the $A_i$. Maybe they meant this?

Comment: It's from a lecture of my university in Probability II. My professor proposed this exercise saying that we should discover Y by ourselves and then do the math to reach $1/p$ (The expected value of geometric distribution). Unfortanely, he didn't provide anymore context or tips :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $Y$ is the random variable, defined on the same probability space, as $1$ if $X$ succeeds on the first 'go' and as zero otherwise, you can determine $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ in terms of $\Bbb E[X]$. Assume $0<p<1$ (the $p=0$ case is forbidden and $p=1$ is trivial).

Motivation: this was just the simplest relevant thing I could think of. I think choosing $Y$ to be $1$ if $X$ succeeds within $n$ turns and $0$ otherwise would also work, but $n=1$ is by far the easiest to handle.

From your explicit calculation of $\Bbb E[X|Y]$, conclude algebraically that $\Bbb E[X]=1/p$.

Note: I think phrasing this in terms of the law of total expectation is silly. We could turn this argument into a direct and elegant proof that doesn't require the intermediary $Y$.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the idea behind this problem too. I solved it as you mentioned, but it just ended in the basic expected value formula, right? Or did I do something wrong? I'll try to contact my professor about it and then return here with an answer. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @user38473 No worries. What should have happened: you figure out that: $$\Bbb E[X|Y]=\begin{cases}1&X=1\\\Bbb E[X]+1&X>1\end{cases}$$So that: $$\Bbb E[X]=\Bbb E[\Bbb E[X|Y]]=p+(1-p)(\Bbb E[X]+1)$$And some algebra gives from this that $\Bbb E[X]=1/p$

Comment: There is no need to go into series notations or any standard formulae for $\Bbb E[X|Y]$, just the raw measure-theoretic definition. Since $Y$ is just an indicator function it's necessarily the case that $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ is a constant function, constant on the event $(X=1)$ and its complement. We require that $\int_{(X=1)}X=\int_{(X=1)}\Bbb E[X|Y]$, easily giving $\Bbb E[X|Y|=1$ on $(X=1)$. You can make a direct calculation for the event $(X>1)$

Comment: I'm sorry for deleting the comment, I was going to write it on the post, since it was really bad at the comments.  And I'm afraid I don't have the necessary knowledge to follow your explanation yet :( I don't understand concepts like "the raw measure-theoretic definition", "indicator function" or anything that comes from them.

Comment: @user38473 Ah ok, fair enough. Indicator function means this: If $\Omega$ is some probability space, an "indicator function" or indicator variable is just like this "$Y$" which I made: it's a random variable which is $1$ exactly when a particular event occurs, and $0$ at any other time. For example, if your probability space is the set of outcomes of a dice roll, an indicator variable might be the variable which is $1$ if you roll a six and is zero at all other times.

Comment: Measure theory is an enormous subject and has been used very successfully to give probability theory a proper, rigorous treatment. For our purposes, the definition of $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ comes down to this; $X$ is defined on some probability space. We make a new probability space by discarding all the events that don't change the value of $Y$ (loosely speaking); we only keep information about events which can affect $Y$. In this case, the events that affect $Y$ are precisely the events $(X=1)$ and $(X>1)$. (cont.)

Comment: The conditional expectation $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ is defined (in the measure theoretic treatment), loosely, as the random variable $Z$ with the following property; it only depends on the events which affect $Y$ (so all the other events which affect $X$ but not $Y$, these are ignored) but it still "looks like" $X$; if $A$ is an event affecting $Y$ then we want $\Bbb E[X|A]$ to equal $\Bbb E[Z|A]$. So $Z$ keeps the information about expected values, but it only depends on $Y$ (basically)

Comment: I admit that this is confusing because conditional expectation, at the introductory level, is given many different definitions, many of which don't view it as a random variable

Comment: So anyway, in our case, we want to make a random variable $Z$ which only depends on the events $(X=1)$ and $(X>1)$. Clearly, $\Bbb E[X|X=1]=p$. So we need $\Bbb E[Z|X=1]$ to also equal $p$. But because $Z$ isn't allowed to depend on anything smaller than $(X=1)$, it has to be constant; the only constant that works is just "$1$", so $Z=1$ when $X=1$. What about $(X>1)$? Well, $\Bbb E[X|X>1]$ is just equal to $(1-p)(1+\Bbb E[X])$. This is basically because geometric distributions have no memory; it looks the same on $(X>1)$. (cont.)

Comment: So we need $Z$ to be constant and to have $\Bbb E[Z|X>1]=(1-p)(1+\Bbb E[X])$. The only constant that works is $Z\equiv1+\Bbb E[X]$ on the event $(X>1)$. So that hopefully explains what my earlier comments meant. But, it's a different definition to the one you're used to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience for explaining your thinking in so much details. I learned some new things by reading your explanation and I really appreciate it. But I think that from each new explanation you'll give me, it'll appear three more doubts :( I'll consider your answer as the one that helped the most and leave this problem for my professor to solve in class. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: @user38473 You're very welcome. There are a few questions about conditional expectation on this site, I think, you could read for more explanations/examples